# can't inspect run-time values in EPIC PERL eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I'm using `eclipse` 4.29 (into which I've installed the `EPIC PERL` plugin) in which, according to the documentation, right-clicking on the code editor is supposed to offer, amongst others, `inspect` and `execute` options on the current selection, allowing me to examine run-time values, but my `eclipse` installation offers no such options ...

Here's a screen-shot: [image]

Does anybody know whether is the problem lies with `EPIC` (that is , does it have this capability?), or with my particular installation?

Russell

Comment: *"right-clicking on the code editor is supposed to offer, amongst others, inspect and execute options on the current selection"* To clarify, could you show a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the requested screen-shot, since I'm new enough to Stack Overflow to not know goew to do o so from a comment :-(

Comment: There should be a "Debug" sub menu under the "Run" menu. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 now: https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/856ebd59225b704f8de273f686911bac

Comment: The commands in that menu (such as stepping) are working fine:  it's inspecting values at run-time that's not available ...

Comment: *"it's inspecting values at run-time that's not available*" Not sure what you mean, in the link in my previous comment I showed you how to inspect a value of variable at run time. Please clarify what you mean by "inspecting values at run-time"

Comment: Well, if a variable contains a certain value at run-time, I want a window of some kind to display that value.  At the moment, the "variables" window does this fine, but Eclipse, not myself, chooses which variables to display.  The "watch" window would, ordinarily, do this, but its values yield an "evaluation error"

Comment: *"The watch window would, ordinarily, do this, but its values yield an evaluation error"* : Yes I think I understand what you mean now. I tested with a Python project, and there you can right click an expression when debugging and select "Watch" from the popup menu. In the Perl project however, the "Watch" menu item seems to be missing from the popup menu.

Comment: There is another option that allows you to enter manually an expression to evaluate, see: http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s04.php#N10A14

Comment: Thanks to the above link, I found that "PERL Expressions View", (which I'd, until now, missed), which is close enough to what I need: thanks for your help!